# jQuery multiple toggle to be valid the next div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help in jQuery. 
There is a well-working-toogle script when I use it only once at the webpage. But I would like if it worked in multiple solution. The link (id="clickme") which is clicked to be valid the next div which contains the id="me".

```
<p class="css_style" id="clickme" style="cursor:pointer;">Details</p>
...
Here it is programming.
... 
<div id="me" style="display: none; background-color: yellow;">
Here is the text, which appears for clicking above.
</div>

<p class="css_style" id="clickme" style="cursor:pointer;">Details</p>
...
Here it is programming.
... 
<div id="me" style="display: none; background-color: blue;">
Here is the text, which appears for clicking above.
</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#clickme').click(function() {
              $('#me').animate({
                   height: 'toggle'
                   }, 200
              );
         });
    });
</script>
```

Could you help me to solve this problem.
Thank in advance.

Atti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to toogle only the next "me" you should do like that :

```
<p class="clickme" style="cursor:pointer;">Details</p>
...
Here it is programming.
... 
<div id="me" style="display: none; background-color: yellow;">
Here is the text, which appears for clicking above.
</div>

<p class="clickme" style="cursor:pointer;">Details</p>
...
Here it is programming.
... 
<div id="me" style="display: none; background-color: blue;">
Here is the text, which appears for clicking above.
</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.clickme').click(function() {
              //.next take the next DOM element
              $(this).next('#me:first').animate({
                   height: 'toggle'
                   }, 200
              );
         });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT : UPDATE, try it now

Check that fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/fovk8ntu/1/

Comment: Sorry I've put class two time in "p" tag, that explain why it doesn't work

Comment: The problem does not come from the double class. There was an apostrof failure too, but for clicking the details does not open.

Comment: You're right but it come from both. I'll edit for the apostrof

Comment: i mean that I cut the double class, but there is no result of it.

Comment: You don't need the use the document.ready in a fiddle, but you need to add the jquery library

Comment: oh, I like it. Only one thing is missing. when I click the second the first has to be closed. For this do you have any idea?

Comment: Plz Vote, valid the answer and then create a new ticket with this new problem

Comment: Brr. It is applied on webpage not opening the box. Is it possible that there some divs before that div is coming for which is applied the class="clickme"?

Comment: next div means that it is found wherever in the code. http://jsfiddle.net/axea78fc/3/

Answer (score 0):

dont use id but using class="clickme"

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
                 $('.clickme').click(function() {
                      $(this).next('#me').animate({
                           height: 'toggle'
                           }, 200
                      );
                 });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p  class="clickme" style="cursor:pointer;">Details</p>
    ...
    Here it is programming.
    ... 
    <div id="me" style="display: none; background-color: yellow;">
    Here is the text, which appears for clicking above.
    </div>
    
    <p class="clickme" style="cursor:pointer;">Details</p>
    ...
    Here it is programming.
    ... 
    <div id="me" style="display: none; background-color: blue;">
    Here is the text, which appears for clicking above.
    </div>
```

Comment: Now the problem is, that the two clickme only opens the same (first) div. :(

Comment: this is the jsfiddle with your proposed modificication. Here it is the code does not working at all. On the webpage it is all right for only one div. http://jsfiddle.net/dow0z0fp/2/

Comment: Actually when I click the first details open the text between the first and the second details, and if you click the second details the first closed, and the second open.

Comment: using one class, conflict class='css_style' and class='clickme' @Atti

Answer (score 0):

one page only have one id !
if there are more than 2 id, you should use class instead of id.
My English is poor, I hope that you can underst